# In iOS, why does dragging beyond a UIImageView not end a PanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got a UIImageView with a PanGestureRecognizer attached. When I drag outside the ImageView, I'd like to think of the pan as ended, but apparently the GestureRecognizer keeps on firing as if I'm still dragging on the view.

[image: Pan ended illustration]

I'm guessing it has something to do with my misunderstanding of the view bounds.

What's the correct way to know when the pan has left the UIImageView it is attached to?

Comment: try recognize's - (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView*)view.

Comment: the view bounds is used to determine which view receive touch event. when a view receive began event, it will also receive other touch event, like moved, cancelled, ended. no matter how the touch position changes. if you want gesture fails when out view bounds, you need to test this situation yourself.

Comment: Thanks @SolaWing that explains it for me. I was confused. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OC:

```
CGPoint p = [recognize locationInView:imageView];
bool out = ![imageView pointInside:p withEvent:nil];
```

Swift:

```
var p = recognize.locationInView(self.view);
var out = !self.view.pointInside(point, withEvent: nil);
```

if out is YES. pan has left the imageView.

Comment: Thanks @mistyhua Are you quick with Swift? What's the Swift equivalent if you are? I can figure it out otherwise.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master. it is same.